# How to remove string items from a list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list of string items like this:

```
myList = ['CLIPPOLY', 'ExternalCrosswalk','CrossReference', 'SourceCitation', 'Status', 'Waterbody', 'N_1_EDesc', 'N_1_ETopo', 'N_1_JDesc', 'N_1_JTopo', 'N_1_Props', 'Line']
```

I want to remove any item that has 'N_1' from my list. Simple right? I tried this:

```
 for item in myList:
     if 'N_1' in item:
         myList.remove(item)
         print("Removed item: {}".format(item))
```

This outputs:

```
Removed item: N_1_EDesc
Removed item: N_1_JDesc
Removed item: N_1_Props
```

When I print out myList again, I can still see that not all of the items with 'N_1' were removed. Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

```
 print(myList)
```

Returns

```
['CLIPPOLY','ExternalCrosswalk','CrossReference','SourceCitation','Status','Waterbody','N_1_ETop', 'N_1_JTopo','Line']
```

NOTE- I've also just tried creating a list of names I wanted removed, like this :

```
bad_list = ['N_1_EDesc', 'N_1_ETopo', 'N_1_JDesc', 'N_1_JTopo', 'N_1_Props']
```

I then tried to remove an item if it was in the bad_list, but I had the same effect.

```
for item in myList:
    if item in bad_list:
        myList.remove(item)
        print("Removed item: {}".format(item))
```

Comment: The problem is that when you remove an item, the actual list contents are now out of sync with the original `for item in myList` loop.

Comment: The usual solution is to not modify the original list at all, but instead make a new list that has only the items you want to keep.

Comment: @JohnGordon: You can always assign to `myList[:]` to modify the original `list` if you need to ensure other aliases to that original `list` see the change. And as a bonus, it's faster than what the OP is trying to do; iterating with `.remove`, even if it worked, would be `O(n²)`, while making the new `list` and replacing the contents of the original `list` is just a couple of `O(n)` operations. `myList[:] = [item for item in myList if not item.startswith('N_1')]` seems closest to the OP's intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use list comprehension as given below:

```
myList=[x for x in myList if 'N_1' not in x]
```

The above code will overwrite the existing list by taking items that does not contain 'N_1'.

Comment: That will differ in behavior if `myList` is an alias of the `list` you're trying to modify (e.g. the caller's `list` needs to change when `myList` was received as an argument), and rebinding it to a *new* `list` won't change the original `list` held in other aliases. Making it `myList[:] = [x for x in myList if 'N_1' not in x]` will modify the *original* `list` so all aliases see the change as well.